# What is the IPA classification for these sounds?

Tags: phonetics, dialects, spanish

I'd like to know the classification for these sounds: **g**, **c**, **z** and **s** as in **g**itano, tren**c**ito, **z**orro and ca**s**a, in Latino American Spanish. For instance, which ones are fricatives, or affricates, etc.

Comment: This is something you can refer to:                                                          https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spanish_phonology#Consonants

Comment: @WiccanKarnak [h] is missing in that table.

Comment: @rraallvv [h] is a variant of [s] and sometimes [x], it's discussed at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spanish_phonology#Realization_of_.2Fs.2F

Comment: @MarkBeadles Hmm... I'd bet [h] would be the most common realization for /x/ from movies dubbed for hispano-american audiences, but now I'm not so sure.

Comment: @rraalw I referred to it since you mentioned only _"g, c, z and s"_ also I see that now you have your question answered successfully, so I won't edit that to add an _h_ reference, still tell me if you need references.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The IPA symbols [ɡ, c] are termed "plosives", and [z, s] are "fricatives". This is true no matter what language you are talking about. There is no IPA category "affricate", although phoneticians do talk about such things (from the IPA perspective, they are sequences of plosive plus fricative). However, the letters *g, c, z, s* used in Spanish spelling are not used as IPA symbols (and *g* is not an IPA symbol at all). I believe that the letters *z, s* as used in Spanish always stand for fricatives, whereas the letters *g, c* can stand for many different things, especially *c*. Your question is about the letters used in spelling Spanish, which have some relation to phonemes, which in turn have some relation to IPA transcriptional symbols – "gitano" only contains letters, not sounds, and those letters represent certain sounds.

Comment: A bit confusing to write "g is not an IPA symbol at all" when the default typeface for this site uses single-story g (I think you were talking about the preference to avoid two-story g in IPA, right?)

Comment: It is a nuisance that g=67 sometimes appears the same as ɡ=261, depending on the font used to render the text (likewise [a] and [ɑ] vs. italic *[a] and [ɑ]*, though here the distinction is kept unlike Times-based web pages.

Comment: Interestingly, in my browser they still look different, though very similar. g ɡ